# Retrieve object sent from Python client to an Azure Service Bus Topic

Tags: c#, python, azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I am subscribed to an Azure Service Bus Topic and I am trying to retrieve objects sent from my Python client. But in my receiving end all I get is something like this:

```
<__main__.User object at 0x02F694F0>
<models.AssetPayload object at 0x038EA930>
```

I have tried receiving in python and in .NET. Here is a dummy code of what I have tried:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, user_id, name):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name


user = User('123456', 'Shaphil')

# Send Message to 'myTopic'
msg = Message(bytes(user))
bus_service.send_topic_message('myTopic', msg)

# Receive Messages
msg = bus_service.receive_subscription_message('myTopic', 'AllMessages', peek_lock=False)
print msg.body
```

Receiving dummy code in C#:

```
var message = subscriptionClient.Receive();
var json = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

How can I retrieve the User object (the user_id and name) that was sent by the sender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to call `bytes()` on the `.__dict__` member of that instance. That is a standard Python `dict`and if your class is simple it will be JSON like serializable to `"{'user_id': '123456', 'name': 'Shaphil'}"`.

Please try the following code snippet to create the `Message` object:

`msg = Message(bytes(user.__dict__))`

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hey, actually that is what I just did as I couldn't find any other solution. But I would obviously like to know if there other ways of doing it. Thanks for the reply though, it brought me some confidence.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
message = Message(json.dumps(<dictionary to be converted into bytes>).encode('utf-8'))
```